# Clear Textinput text and hide clearBtn

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a Textinput field (search bar/box) from JQuery Mobile.

I'm wanting to know whether there's any way (via a function) to:

1. Clear the text value
2. Hide the "X" or clear button (An auto-generated JQuery Mobile button inside the search bar, not the one under the search bar)
3. Remove focus from the search bar (Textinput)

I've tried using `$("#topSearch").val("")`, but this doesn't meet the second criteria. I've also tried `$(".ui-input-clear").click()` and `$("#topSearch").blur()`, but this breaks my program in an unusual way, most likely linked to a way that I populate the lists. I've also tried manually using `$(".ui-input-clear").hide()` or `.toggle()`, but JQuery Mobile seems to handle it differently (as it won't reappear).

There must be a proper way since JQuery Mobile already does it - when you hit enter on the textinput box the text will clear, the "X" gone and the focus removed.

Either a suggestion how to do it or how to wade through JQuery Mobile's code to find how they do it would be awesome, I've tried the latter with no luck.

Here's a(n updated) fiddle for people to play around in: http://jsfiddle.net/pWQjZ/1/
Not entirely sure how helpful it'll be.

Another edit: To specify, this function has to be called via a function not related to the `.ui-input-clear` "X" button. The search bar gets cleared by a different function when something else is clicked - rather than the "X" (which already works).

Comment: Please post your markup or create a fiddle for the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know which functions to use, just use all of them at the same time inside a click event handler.

eg:

```
$(".ui-input-clear").click(function(){
    $("#topSearch").val("");
    $("#topSearch").blur();
    $(".ui-input-clear").closest('.ui-btn').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile hides your element and wraps it in a new div which is styled to look and behave like a button.

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pWQjZ/4/)**. This is your updated fiddle.

```
$('#topSearch').focus(function(){
    $('.ui-input-clear').show();     
});

$('#topSearch').keydown(function(e){

    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode=='13'){                                  //enter key press
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).blur();                                   //focus out

        $('.ui-input-clear').hide();
    }

});
```

The current button is wrapped in a `<div>` by jQuery mobile,

```
<div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="null" data-iconpos="null" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">X</span></span><input type="button" value="X" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false"></div>
```

---

Another solution for the `hide()` event to work, wrap your button in a `<div>` like this.

```
<div id="someid">
    <input type="button" class="ui-input-clear" value="Button"/>
</div>
```